# how to remove scrollbar after datastore removed?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i have a window with grid panel as the content...

1. when the window first shown, my store is empty and i can't see the scrorllbar (good)
2. when i load the data to store, i can see the scrollbar (good)
3. when i remove all data from store, i can still see the scrollbar and scrollable. when exactly there's no data in view (bad)

so my question is my title, *how to remove scrollbar after datastore removed*

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/43LbU/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its is a open bug. Sencha team promises to fix it it 4.0.7. Have a look at [this discussion](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136678-OPEN-EXTJSIV-2536-4.0.2-store.removeAll%28%29-does-not-remove-grid.verticalScroller) at Sencha forum.

One possible solution given in the forum, is to hide the scrollbar using hideVerticalScroller() method. I did try it on fiddle but was not successful 100% (may be something to do with fiddle). I had to click "remove data" button twice to remove the scroll bar:

```
 handler:function(){
        storeSr.removeAll();
        gridSr.hideVerticalScroller();
 }
```

On the forum, they suggest doing (And this works!):

```
storeSr.removeAll();
var data = [];
var store = gridSr.getStore();
store.loadData(data, false);

if (data.length == 0) {
    gridSr.hideVerticalScroller();
}
```

Comment: thanks .. i just figured why didn't i look it up in their forum before ask here.. hehehe peace :)